# How do you choose a yeast?

Tags: yeast

What characteristics do you look for in a yeast to pair with your recipe?
Is there a common reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me some styles showcase yeast like Belgians, Hefes, some English styles, etc.  Others showcase malts or hops and yeast shouldn't play much of a role.  For me I generally stick with some clean ale yeast like 1056 or Pacman for IPA's, Blondes, etc.  And then obviously for something like a hefe I choose 3068.

As I reference, if you car about style guidelines, look at the BJCP style guidelines for whatever your making.  They will usually mention what role yeast character should or should not play.

Answer (score 3):

There's a great reference for yeast and what characters they lend to beer that I use all of the time to figure out what flavors I want to incorporate into my brew from yeast.

[BYO Yeast Guide](http://www.byo.com/resources/yeast)

Back in another life, I was working on making a searchable yeast database, but that site is now mostly defunct and out of date.  I still use that little app occasionally, though.  I can't post two links in a post right now, so I can't give you a link.  Maybe someday.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I bookmarked it.
Also, you can add links with the "annotation style" outlined in this guide: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Ah, so you can.  Here's the link to the tool I built a few years back.  Like I say, out of date, but still fairly useful.

http://www.thebrewguide.com/searchyeast.php

Answer (score 1):

I normally brew "to style", meaning that when I make a beer I choose ingredients that match a particular style.  Right now I am drinking my Classic American Pilsner.  I drink enough beers to know, in general, the flavor characteristics I like in a beer and choose a yeast that produces them.

Brewing to style narrows your yeast choices.  When choosing a yeast for the CAP I reviewed the characteristics of the White Labs and Wyeast lager offerings.  I also listened to the Jamil Show's [episode](http://thebrewingnetwork.com/shows/The-Jamil-Show/American-Pilsner-The-Jamil-Show-05-22-06) on the style.  From the flavor profile descriptions I choose a yeast that best suits my taste (and fermentation capabilities).

When not brewing to style, such as my [Rye of the Hurricane](http://midnighthourbrewery.blogspot.com/search/label/rye) recipe, I pick a yeast that compliments the flavors I want to get out of the beer.  I like British ales, so I often choose London Ale III from Wyeast.

Some good advice, which I have yet to follow, is to really get to know a single strain of yeast. Brew a number of recipes with a single yeast. That way you know enough to make it produce the flavors you are looking for rather than choosing a yeast for the flavors it produces.